# If I award a bounty can I raise another on the same question?

Tags: support, bounties

I have a bounty that is about to expire from its 24 hour grace period. None of the answers actually work. [One of the answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20675406/575530) has proved useful, in that I have learnt something useful from it, but [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20712457/575530) looks promising if the answerer follows up to address my comment. I am tempted to award the bounty to the first of these answers and then raise a second bounty *on the same question* but it is not clear to me from the [set bounties wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) whether they can be awarded a second time on the same question.

Comment: Yes you can. It has to be double the previous amount, up to a maximum of 500.